# java.lang.Class cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn when date capturing and string formatting

Tags: java, date, casting, clojure, interop

I'm not really seeing where I'm going wrong here, especially since I hit upon a minor variation at one point that allowed this, but couldn't explain why it worked. Please also tell me, in a more overall sense, what the issue is in general when you are having casting problems of a Java class to a Clojure Interface Function (IFn) and how you can debug it. Thank you.

```
(defn date
  []
  (new java.util.Date))

(defn x
  []
  (.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat "YYYY-MM-DD")(new java.util.Date)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `.` right at the end of `SimpleDateFormat`. Right now, you're calling the class as a function, hence that exception. Adding a dot at the end makes it an instantiation.

You can do the same with `(new java.util.Date)` - it can be replaced with `(java.util.Date.)`.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that worked. It's the little things isn't it?

Comment: Clojure uses a trailing `.` (dot) character like `(Date.)` to construct a new Date object, instead of typing `new Date()` like in Java. It is also legal Clojure to type `(new Date)` (without the dot), but in normal code the use of the trailing `.` is just about universal.